Device tree alias added in overlay seems not to be loaded
I'm using LS1028a-rdb (kernel 5.15) board which in its device tree defines the following aliases:
aliases: aliases {
    crypto = &crypto;
    serial0 = &duart0;
    serial1 = &duart1;
    mmc0 = &esdhc;
    mmc1 = &esdhc1;
    rtc1 = &ftm_alarm1;
};

I added my overlay which also adds one more alias to aliases node.
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

&aliases {
    rtc2 = &rv3028;
};

&i2c0_mux {
    rv3028: rtc@52 {
        compatible = "microcrystal,rv3028";
        reg = <0x52>;
        /* trickle-resistor-ohms = <3000>; */
    };
};

I added some prints to drivers/of/base.c
pr_err("adding DT alias:%s: stem=%s id=%i node=%pOF\n",
     ap->alias, ap->stem, ap->id, np);

Below is the output log from booting process:
[    0.000000] OF: adding DT alias:serial0: stem=serial id=0 node=/soc/serial@21c0500
[    0.000000] OF: adding DT alias:serial1: stem=serial id=1 node=/soc/serial@21c0600
[    0.000000] OF: adding DT alias:mmc0: stem=mmc id=0 node=/soc/mmc@2140000
[    0.000000] OF: adding DT alias:mmc1: stem=mmc id=1 node=/soc/mmc@2150000
[    0.000000] OF: adding DT alias:rtc1: stem=rtc id=1 node=/soc/timer@2810000

As you can see there is nothing about rtc2 added in my overlay.
However things get more strange when I look at /proc/device-tree/aliases because there is the rtc2 entry with the following content:
/fragment@2/__overlay__/i2c@7/rtc@52

Why is that and how to fix it?
The overlay is loaded by U-BOOT using the following extlinux.conf:
label LS1028ARDB_DT_OVERLAY_TESTER
    kernel /Image
    fdt /fsl-ls1028a-rdb-ls1028ardb-tr.dtb
    fdtoverlays /devicetree/eval-tester-overlay.dtbo
    append root=/dev/mmcblk0p${active_part} rootwait console=ttyS0,115200

however I tried to manually load all artifacts in uboot using fdt commands with the same result.

Is the overlay being applied by the bootloader before it boots the Linux kernel, or is Linux loading the overlay at runtime?

Yes it is loaded by u-boot. I updated my question accordingly.

"Below is the output log from booting process: ..." - You seem focused exclusively on "alias". The alias is useless if the underlying device is not active. Why aren't you debugging the status of this rv3028 device and its driver? What about its parent; is that I2C master controller even enabled?
